# Inserting value instead of label for autocomplete textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I want to display label on autocomplete textbox, but want to store values behind jquery autcomplete. The label is populating correctly, however, behind it stores the label instead of value. How would i use the autocomplete jquery textbox to store values instead of label. The labels are the names and values are their emails. Below is the jquery code.

**Note:- I'm using dictionary for using both values in c#**

```
$(function () {

            var arr = [];

            var arrName = [];

            $('#<%=NotifyUsersEmail.ClientID %>').tagit({

                autocomplete: {
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 1,
                    source: function (request, response) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Case.aspx/GetTags") %>',
                            data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                arr = $.map(data.d, function (el) { return el });

                                response($.map(data.d, function (item,index) {

                                    return {
                                        label: item,
                                        val: index
                                    }
                                }))
                            },

                            error: function (response) {

                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                        alert(ui.item.val)
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
// here if i use $(this).val(ui.item.val); then the textbox value is changed to emails but i want to keep the labels displayed

                    },
                },
                //availableTags: arr,



                //beforeTagAdded: function (event, ui) {


                //    // do something special
                //    if ($.inArray(ui.tagLabel, arr) == -1) {
                //        return false;
                //    }
                //}
            });





        });
```

Comment: Try with `ui.item.value`

Comment: If you can see, i already mentioned that line in comments. Writing this line of code, overwrites the label, which i don't want @SilentCoder

Comment: I mean to use `alert(ui.item.value) insteat of  `val`

Comment: @SilentCoder alert(ui.item.value) displays the label text.

Comment: Do you have that email values in your html?

Comment: The email values are being generated through code behind using dictionary along with employee names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165454/discussion-between-silentcoder-and-user100020).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work find, Check your response and the format of the response

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      {"label":"ActionScript","val":"someemail#some.lk"},
      {"label":"Script","val":"abc@abc.com"},
      {"label":"Raction","val":"jkl@wsd.com"},
      {"label":"BctionScript","val":"QQQQ@SSSS.com"},
      {"label":"DctionScript","val":"Test@testing.com"}
   
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
          select: function (event, ui) {
                        alert(ui.item.val)
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label);


                    }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```